# iOS Local Notifications after first and last use

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am trying to set up local notifications that are triggered under two circumstances:
- An x number of days after the first use of the app
- In case the user has gone an x number of days without using the app

Is this possible? All the information I have found online is about setting notifications to go off at a specific time, but how can I send depending on the app's first and last use?

Comment: Will be possible with Push Notifications but in Local I think you could try storing two dates in User defaults, the first date from the first launch and the second one every time the app is open and calculate the days.

Comment: You need to schedule the notification when they use the app.  Each time the app comes to the foreground and/or launches you unscheduled the existing notification and schedule a new one for x days time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need a request to register the notifications, and after the notification is granted, you can call the functions that firing the notifications on the specific time.

In `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound]
    center.requestAuthorization(options: options, completionHandler: { granted, error in
        if granted {
            self.setNotificationForFirstTimeUseApp()
            self.setNotificationForLastTimeUseApp()
            print("Notification is granted")
        } else {
            print("Notification is not granted")
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

Create the functions for firing the notification on a specific time:

```
func setNotificationForFirstTimeUseApp() {
    // Check the app, if it is opened before
    if let _ = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "appOpened") as? Bool {
        return
    }

    // Save a flag on preferences that it tells the app is opened for the first time
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "appOpened")

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Using for the first time - Notification" // Add your own title
    content.body = "Awesome thank you for using this application!" // Add your own description
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

    // Specific the time you want to fire the notification (after some days, hours, minutes...)
    if let date = Date.getDateByAdding(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 5) {

        let componentsForFireDate = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .timeZone], from: date)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: componentsForFireDate, repeats: false)

        let identifier = "firstTimeUseApp"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: identifier,
            content: content,
            trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if error != nil {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
                }
            }
        })

        center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
            print(String(format: "PendingNotificationRequests %i", requests.count))
            for req in requests {
                let trigger = req.trigger
                if let trigger = trigger {
                    print("trigger \(trigger)")
                }
            }
        })
    }

}

func setNotificationForLastTimeUseApp () {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Using for the last time - Notification" // Add your own title
    content.body = "You have not used the application for a long time!" // Add your own description
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local

    // Specific the time you want to fire the notification (after some days, hours, minutes...)
    if let date = Date.getDateByAdding(days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 10) {
        let componentsForFireDate = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second, .timeZone], from: date)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: componentsForFireDate, repeats: false)
        let identifier = "lastTimeUseApp"

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(
            identifier: identifier,
            content: content,
            trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        // Remove pending notifications
        center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [identifier])
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            if error != nil {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Something went wrong: \(error)")
                }
            }
        })

        center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
            print(String(format: "PendingNotificationRequests %i", requests.count))
            for req in requests {
                let trigger = req.trigger
                if let trigger = trigger {
                    print("trigger \(trigger)")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And finally, add this function. It will calculate a future date by adding days, hours, minutes and seconds, from now.

```
extension Date {
    static func getDateByAdding(days: Int, hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) -> Date? {
        let currentDate = Date()
        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        dateComponent.day = days
        dateComponent.hour = hours
        dateComponent.minute = minutes
        dateComponent.second = seconds
        let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: currentDate)
        return futureDate
    }
}
```

I hope this answer will help you with your issue!